# insertAfter() is appending by doubling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to append `tr` after some certian `tr` and i use this code. but it is appending by doubling, first time only 1, second time 2 and third time 6... can someone help me out where this is causing this issue? i just want to add only one `tr` per click.

```
function einfugen(){
  $('#append_tr').bind('click', function(){
    $('<tr><td>new td</td></tr>').insertAfter('#append_tr');
  });
}



<tr id="append_tr"> some data </td>
```

**EDIT**: here is my binding code:

```
<tr id="append_tr"><td> <a onclick="einfugen()"> + add </a> </td></tr>
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `einfugen()` function declares the click handler and it's called from the click event here:

```
<tr id="append_tr"><td> <a onclick="einfugen()"> + add </a> </td></tr>
```

The more you click it, the more click handlers are attached. What you could do instead is remove the `einfugen()` function declaration but move the contents into the DOM ready function instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('#append_tr').on('click', function(){
    $('<tr><td>new td</td></tr>').insertAfter('#append_tr');
  });
});
```

Having the click handler registered there eliminates the need for the inline `onclick` handler code.

Comment: Not exactly, your "first one" is only within the function that `onclick` calls. If the latter is removed, *no* handler will be added.

Comment: @Jack, thanks, you hit the point. i changed the function call to ``$(function(){ })`` now working like a charm :D

Comment: @DavidHedlund Doh! You're right, missed that completely :) updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may be calling the function numerous times.

Don't use `bind` and use `on` (jQuery 1.7):

```
$('#append_tr').on('click', function(){
    $('<tr><td>new td</td></tr>').insertAfter('#append_tr');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

From your edit:

```
 <a onclick="einfugen()">
```

Is the problem.  You are rebinding an event handler each time the link is clicked.

Using the following structure you could do:

```
$("#append_tr").click(function() {
   $("#table").append("<tr><td>New row!</td></tr>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBNbZ/

Comment: Agreed, `on` is the preferred method of binding, but that wouldn't solve this problem.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - I agree it may not solve the problem as I believe the OP is calling the einfugen function more than once.  However no harm in recommending best practices.

Comment: i am not calling function more than once, please see my update.

Comment: @doniyor - I have edited my answer.  From your edit it seems you are binding the event multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're calling `einfugen` more than once. If you only call it once, it will work ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xpeW7/)).

**EDIT:** From your update, yes, you're binding a listener every time the 'add' link is clicked. You're confusing *firing an action* that would be sensible in `onclick`, with *binding a listener to fire at a given event*.

Your `insertAfter` isn't run when `einfugen` is run. `einfugen` just adds a listener that instructs that code to run whenever a click happens. So that call can be made once, initially, and then your listener will always be there. It shouldn't be added at every click.

You could bind the listener initially like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#append_tr').bind('click', function(){
    $('<tr><td>new td</td></tr>').insertAfter('#append_tr');
  });
});
```

Where `$(function() { ... });` is shorthand for running a function on `DOMReady`, i.e. as soon as all DOM nodes are guaranteed to be accessible by the script.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fzjZN/).

Comment: i updated my question, but i dont seem to be calling the function more than once, right?

Comment: Yeap you were ;) Check out Jack's answer

Comment: @doniyor: You *are* calling it more than once, you are calling it *every time the button is clicked*. See my updated answer.